# How do I rename a file that only consists of an extension?

Tags: windows-7

I use the Eclipse IDE to do development work and would like to copy/rename the `.classpath` and/or `.project` files.  Note that these files only have an extension and not a filename.

Windows won't let me change `.classpath` to `.classpath.bak` (or vice versa).

Is there some way to do this other than naming the files in a Unix server and copying them to my Windows machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In all current Windows versions, the extension is *part of* the filename. They have been a single field ever since Windows 95 introduced "Long File Names".

Although Windows Explorer refuses filenames starting with a `.`, this limitation does not apply to Command Prompt, PowerShell, or to alternative file managers such as Total Commander. (Eclipse itself should let you rename as well.)

For example, in Command Prompt you can use:

```
C:\> cd/d C:\Users\Fred\Projects

C:\Users\Fred\Projects\> ren .classpath .classpath.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put an extra dot at the end of the filename.
So, instead of renaming it to

> .classpath

rename it to

> .classpath.

Comment: Then it wouldn't be named .classpath

Comment: Have you at least tried it? This works even on the latest Windows 10 build (1903 atm).

Comment: Still, it is not a new trick, as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24136985/6182286
Microsoft fixed this on a previous update so you can just rename it to '.classpath' and it should work.